# const char * duplicate data inside of std::map in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, struct, std

I have a rare problem.

I've stored a struct into a std::map,
inserted the first data and going normal, but when I try to store more than one struct data, all the `const char*` of all "seconds" values, inside the structs get missing and it gets replaced with the new data.

I resume the code:

```
struct Emitter{

.
.
const char * name;
const char * file;
} 

Emitter metadata;
```

before of i insert the struct, i fill the const char * variable whit this code (i get the info fomr a XML)

```
std::string name_tmp= atts.getString("name", "ed");
char tmp[50];
strcpy(tmp, name_tmp.c_str());
metadata.name= tmp;

std::string file_tmp= atts.getString("file", "ed");
char tmp2[50];
strcpy(tmp2, file_tmp.c_str());
metadata.file= tmp2;
```

the key of the map, is the name inside the Emitter struct;

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Emitter> Dictionary;
typedef std::pair<std::string, Emitter> Defination;

Dictionary::iterator it = map.find(name);

        if (it != map.end())
            map[metadata.name] = data;
        else{

            if (map.size() == 0) 
                map.insert(Defination(metadata.name, metadata));
            else{
                ParticlesDictionary::iterator i = map.begin();
                map.insert(i, Defination(metadata.name, metadata));
            }
        }
```

when i print the process of the inserts stacks output, i get this:

```
// key ---> struct value (name) ---> struct value (file)

//first time
  key1 --> eddy --> fileName1

//second time
  key1 --> eddy1-->fileName2
  key2 --> eddy1-->fileName2

//third time

  key1 --> eddy2-->fileName3
  key2 --> eddy2-->fileName3
  key3 --> eddy2-->fileName3
```

why is this happening?

please help

Comment: You are storing pointers to the same buffer several times in the map. The buffer is reused. When you print the data, you print the contents of the same buffer several times - naturally, you see whatever was stored in it last.

Comment: Show your real code.

Comment: With a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could tell you exactly where your problem is.  Right now, we can only make guesses and general suggestions.

Comment: but its just happening with cons char * variables, with others type of variables keep the info exactly how i parse it.. how can it be only with the const char *,

Comment: *"how can it be only with the const char *"*  Millions of different ways.  Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `const char*` fields are pointing at buffers which do not belong to the `struct`. This means that when the arrays `tmp` and `tmp2` go out of scope, the space they used is available for other data.

In your case, it is reused for the next `struct`. To fix this, you should allocate memory to be owned by the `struct`: either by replacing the `const char*` fields with `std::string` fields, or by using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: thanks my friend i change all my const char * to std::string and works.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are asking a question on SO or you are trying to solve a problem like this yourself, the first step is to build an MVCE or SSCE - a small, discrete reproduction of the problem.

With your code this would focus us on the following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    const char* text;
};

void f(A& a, const char* text) {
    char localTxt[50];
    strcpy(lt, text);
    a.text = localTxt;
}

int main() {
    A a, b;
    f(a, "hello");
    f(b, "world");
    std::cout << "But afterwards:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a = " << a.text << ", b = " << b.text << "\n";   
}
```

We've discarded most of what you were doing here and honed in on "what happens when I put this value into a structure".

And the problem here is that `localText` exists on the stack, we took its address and put *that* into the struct. A pointer is a numeric value containing an address. Nothing magical happens when we do this:

```
char a[] = "hello";
char* b = a;
```

`b` now *points* to `a`, there is still only one copy of the string.

Meanwhile, the whole chunk of code seems likely to cause exactly this kind of problem. Would it not make your life significantly simpler to do the following:

```
class Emitter {
    std::string name, file;
};

void myFunc() {
     metadata.name = atts.getString("name", "ed");
     metadata.file = atts.getString("file", "ed");
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, you may want to consider:

```
const std::string& name = atts.getString("name", "ed");
metadata.name = new char[] (name.length() + 1); // +1 for \0
std::copy(metadata.name, name.c_str());
```

But be aware you are now responsible for `delete[]`ing the memory:

```
class Emitter {
    const char* name;
    const char* file;

    Emitter() : name(nullptr), file(nullptr) {}
    ~Emitter() {
        if (name)
            delete [] name;
        if (file)
            delete [] file;
    }
    // ...
};
```